# Check if a set of related rows exist

Tags: sql, database, h2

I want to manage sets of things in a database. Assume the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Sets (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(64));
CREATE TABLE SetItems (fkSet BIGINT, item BIGINT, FOREIGN KEY (fkSet) REFERENCES Sets(id));
```

I could create Sets by inserting a row into table `Sets`, and add one or more rows into `SetItems` with the corresponding `fkSet`.

Getting the items of a specific set is easy, it's basically `SELECT * FROM SetItems WHERE fkSet = :id`.

**Problem:** Now I want to find out if a set exists, given a set of SetItems.

Example: I want to find if there is a set with the items `2` and `5`.

**What I tried:**

**(1)** I could try something like:

```
SELECT s.fkSet FROM Sets s, SetItems i1, SetItems i2
              WHERE s.id = i1.fkSet AND i1.item = 2
                AND s.id = i2.fkSet AND i2.item = 5;
```

But such an approach has several drawbacks:

- I guess it scales very badly if I need to check for more SetItems.
- I need to put together the sql-query with string concatenation which I dislike, increasing the chances for an injection attack.
- it could also find sets which have additional items besides 2 and 5, which I would not like.

To better prevent SQL-Injections, I would prefer a way where I could use Prepared Statements. Technically, I could assemble the query-string for a prepared statement using String concatenation, and then set the query parameters, but this approach feels wrong somehow.

**(2)** Another solution: I could first get all sets the first SetItem is part of, and then check for each returned Set if it also contains all the other items and none additional ones. If the first SetItem is contained in a large number of Sets, this would result in a large number of queries, which seems inefficient and not scalable.

**(3)** For each SetItem that should be contained, I could get all sets it is in, and then do an intersection in my code outside SQL. This would require at most as many sql queries as there are SetItems to be checked.

**(4)** An alternative would be to store the setItems as a comma-separated list as VARCHAR, sorted in increasing order, directly as an additional column in the table `Sets`. The table SetItems would not be needed then. To check for the existence of a set I could just query if there is a row with the same comma-separated list.  But then queries like "in which set is item xy contained" would not be possible so easily, relying on String-matching in the SQL-query. Not very relational...

**Question:** How can I efficiently query an SQL database if a set of related rows exists?
Should I structure my data differently? Should I use a NoSQL database for such a query?

I'm currently using H2 and would prefer a solution not using some specific SQL-dialect of a single database vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `having` to check how many distinct matches you have per set:

```
select   i.fkSet 
from     SetItems i
where    i.item in (2, 5)
group by s.fkSet
having   count(distinct i.item) = 2
```

Of course, you need to make sure the final number (here 2) corresponds to the number of values you have listed at the `in` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! My actual needs are a bit more complex (I simplified my problem for this question), but this answer should get me going again.